# count number of active days form database

Tags: php, mysql

Hi everyone i have this data in MySQL database.

```
   Date    | status
---------------------
2017-03-01 | active    
2014-03-10 | suspend  
2014-03-20 | active  
2014-03-25 | suspend
```

what i want to do is count and display number of days from the given date that the status was on active state. here is what i tried so far

```
foreach ($get_status as $status) {
    if ($status['status'] == 'suspended') {
        $date1 = date_create($status['date']);
        $date2 = date_create("2017-03-01");
        $diff = date_diff($date2, $date1);
        $active_days += $diff->format("%a days");
        echo $active_days;
    }
}
```

i am expecting the output to be +14 days , but this code/algorithm is not giving me the right calculation and i don't know what to do.please help a brother out!

Comment: change this line `if ($status['status'] == 'suspended') {` to `if ($status['status'] == 'suspend') {` as your db value

Comment: I think I'd be tempted to solve this in the query itself

Comment: i am looking for the right calculation. i already have figured that out on my main source code. please take a look at the calculation solution instead of word errors.

Answer (score 0):

I got your issue you can fix this by replacing

```
$active_days += $diff->format("%a days");
```

With

```
$active_days += $diff->days;
```

It will work fine.

Comment: $diff->days will give you exact days of difference.

Comment: $diff->days . . . . where did "days" comes from?

Comment: $diff is a object it contain all the diff values ,you can see it by var_dump($diff).