# using list() constructer for array

Tags: php

I have multiple dates to calculate on database. They are fetched and stored in an array.

How can I have variables for each of the returned values, since I don't know how many of the dates are returned?

Here is what I tried so far:

```
$get_status = $truckerController->status($gid);
$active_days = 0;
$active_d = array();
foreach ($get_status as $trucker) {
$active_d[] = $trucker->date;
}
list($date1, $date2) = $active_d;
```

So what I want is to have more than two or three parameters inside `list()` based on the array value size. Please help me out or suggest other ways to handle this issue.

Comment: *"how can i have variables for each of the returned values since i don't know how many of the dates are returned"* -- how do you intend to use the generated variables since you don't know how many of them will be returned? An array is the solution because this is the purpose of an array: to store a list of similar values, without caring how many of them are.

Comment: Why would you want to make a variable of all of the items in an array? Seems very not best practice. Isn't there another way of solving your problem without list()?

Comment: i am trying to calculate date. the active date starts on 2017-05-03 and suspended on 2017-05-23. so the wants for how many days it was active starting from 2017-05-01 - 2017-05-30. so i want the answer to be 13 days. how can i achieve this calculation. i used date_create() and date_diff() but i am not getting the right answer. please take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44602015/count-number-of-active-days-form-database/44602188?noredirect=1#comment76192022_44602188

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the whole approach is correct, but you can try with something like this.

```
$get_status = $truckerController->status($gid);
$active_days = 0;
$active_d = array();
$i = 0;
foreach ($get_status as $trucker) {
    $i++;
    $active_d["date".$i] = $trucker->date;
}
extract($active_d);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php